# su on perl script doesn't work from crontab

Tags: linux, cron, perl

I have a perl script running o.k. on unix machines and manually from root user but not from crontab on linux machine:

the problematic command is: su - $user

```
system("su - togui103 -c \"/home/togui103/RunEnv/scripts/tomcatkill.csh\"");
```

command on crontab:

```
23 59 * * * /home/togui103/RunEnv/scripts/tc-rotate.pl > /home/togui103/RunEnv/scripts/tc-rotate.log
```

please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to capture the stderr from your script

```
23 59 .../tc-rotate.pl 2>/tmp/script.log >/home/...
```

and then examine the log for error messages

**EDIT:** Responding to the comment:

Entries in crontab have a fairly restricted environment so the environment variables that you list aren't available, You can though set them in your [crontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) file e.g.

```
APACHE_HOME=/some/path
CATALINA_HOME=/some/other/path
RUN_ENV=someValue
23 59 * * * /home/togui103/RunEnv/scripts/tc-rotate.pl > /home/togui103/RunEnv/scripts/tc-rotate.log
```

Comment: APACHE_HOME: Undefined variable. CATALINA_HOME: Undefined variable. RUN_ENV: Undefined variable. RUN_ENV: Undefined variable.            it happen since 'su' is not execute and the script apachekill.csh requires these variables

Answer (score 0):

If the variables are set in the scope of your perl script you should try su -m

> -m, --preserve-environment
>                do not reset environment variables

Your command can be:

```
system("su -m togui103 -c \"/home/togui103/RunEnv/scripts/tomcatkill.csh\"");
```

Comment: hi, I have the same result I tried also: system("su -s \"/home/$user/.cshrc\" -c \"/home/$user/RunEnv/scripts/apachekill.csh\" $user");   it seems that it initialize the variables but don't run the *.csh script

Comment: Does it work outside the perl script if you enter it manually?
And could you add the output from "ls -l /home/$user/RunEnv/scripts/apachekill.csh" ?

Comment: yes, if I run the script manually from the root it works (it also works on solaris sparc from the crontab and also on my local linux machine), maybee the problem is related to the machine crontab definitions.

Comment: anyone can help?